# One structure being stored within another

Tags: c, graph, nodes, structure

I'm trying to understand why the assignment `g.node = n1;` isn't possible.

Can anyone explain? 
The idea is to create a graph with nodes using structures. I thought this method would work, but I get `error: incompatible types in assignment` for `g.node = n1;`

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int value;
    int *edges;
    int *adj;
}  Node;

typedef struct
{
    Node *node;

} Graph;

void resize_array(char *, int);
void copy_array  (char *, char *);
int main()
{
    Graph g;
    Node n1, n2;
    int edgesS[1] = {9};
    int adjS[1] = {5};
    n1.edges = edgesS;
    n1.adj = adjS;
    n1.value = 1;
    g.node = n1;
    return 0;
}

void resize_array(char * array, int size){array[size] = '\0';}
```

Comment: ***You're grabbing a C tutorial. Now.***

Comment: Exactly as the compiler says: `incompatible types in assignment`. Think about the types for a moment.

Comment: Hesitating whether to vote for closing or not. It's a valid question, just a very, very common one for someone new to C and probably also the whole toolchain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`g.node` is of type `Node*` but `n1` is of type `Node`.  The assignment would be possible as

```
g.node = &n1;
```

instead.  Note that `g.node` merely points to a `Node`; it doesn't contain the memory for one.  With the above simple assignment, when `n1` goes out of scope, the memory `g.node` points to becomes invalid.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was thinking it handled pointers the same as arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to assign a value to a pointer. Try taking the address of *n1* instead, but think about what that means for a minute before you just "make it work".

Comment: Thank you.  I understand what pointers are but was confused about how C handles pointers for various data types.

Answer (score 2):

`Graph` contains a **pointer** to a node.
To accomplish what you want you need to assign the address of the new node.

```
g.node = &n1;
```